# Can you adjust the width of a question in flask-wtforms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a form in flask-wtforms and it is extremely wide:
[image]

I want to reduce the width of the Does the patient smoke and Age questions.
This is the flask-wtforms code I am using:

```
class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    upload = FileField('Select an image:', validators=[
        FileRequired(),
        FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'JPEG', 'PNG', 'JPG'], 'Images only!')
    ])

    smoke = SelectField(
        'Does the patient smoke?',
        choices=[('Yes', 'Yes'), ('No', 'No')]
    )

    name = StringField('Age')

    submit = SubmitField('Get Results')
```

And in the HTML:

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
```

But on mobile devices it isn't that big, so I need to decrease the width and still keep it centered but only for laptops and computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bootstrap would solve your issue.
Bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/
You need to place this stylesheet link in the head element of your .html file.

If you wrap a div with class 'col-md-6' around your form, then it will use half of the width of the screen for the elements. Bootstrap uses a grid 12 segments wide, 6 is telling it to use half of the grid.
If you want the form to be even smaller, try 'col-md-4'. If you want it  a  bit larger, change it to 'col-md-8'.

Let me know how that works for you!
Cheers -Andrew

```
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="col-md-6">
     {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a style directly into the fields using render_kw, e.g.:

```
smoke = SelectField(
    'Does the patient smoke?',
    choices=[('Yes', 'Yes'), ('No', 'No')],
    render_kw={'style': 'width: 10ch'},
)

name = StringField(
    'Age',
    render_kw={'style': 'width: 7ch'},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never using `wtf.quick_form` in my html but when I resizing my form I use this kind of syntax:

```
{{ form.smoke(size=17) }}
{{ form.name(size=17) }}
```